# Mailto in html to open an email account that is NOT default

Tags: mailto

When I click on a mailto link on my .NET web application, it of course defaults to opening my default outlook account.  Is there a way I could code the mailto to open a specific outlook account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really change the client's setting using server-side codes. You can't change anything unfortunately.